# Discord.js bot starts when its not supposed to

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So, i follow this guide, and usually i dont have any problem with it
https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#command-registration
You supposed to creat file called "deploy-commands.js" and run "node deploy-commands.js" to register slash commands.
My "deploy-commands.js"

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const settings = require("./settings.json")
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
// Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(settings.token);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(settings.botid),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

And it kinda works but it also starts a bot for some reason

When i use "node deploy-commands.js" i receive this
[WARNING] The command at path_to_bot\commands\addform.js is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.
Started refreshing 5 application (/) commands.
Successfully reloaded 5 application (/) commands.
Bot ready!
Connected to database

And the bot wont work at all if i dont turn it off and then run it properly with "node bot.js"

//EDIT
Bot.js file(which starts the bot properly when i use "node bot.js") that somehow is being triggered by "discord-commands.js"

```
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, Collection, EmbedBuilder, ModalBuilder, ChannelType, TextInputBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, TextInputStyle, PermissionsBitField,
    ButtonBuilder,
    ButtonStyle
} = require('discord.js');
const settings = require("./settings.json")
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const url = settings.url;
let client1;
const moment = require("moment");

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    ], partials : [Partials.Channel] });


function getCl1(){
    return client1;
}

function setClient1(cli){
    client1 = cli;
}

module.exports.getCl1 = getCl1;
module.exports.url = url;
module.exports.setClient1 = setClient1;


client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    // Set a new item in the Collection with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
    }
}

const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}



client.login(settings.token);
```

//EDIT 2
Addform command has execute and data properties

Comment: Probably need to add that every command has "data" and "executre" property, so the warning makes even less sense

Comment: Is this your `deploy-commands.js` file? Where does that _" [WARNING] The command at path_to_bot\commands\addform.js is missing a required "data" or "execute" property. "_ error coming from?

Comment: Yes, first code is my "deploy-commands.js" which is almost the same as the one in the guide. Also added "bot.js" that somehow starts and gives the warning

Answer (score 1):

To get mongodb client in the commands i used this at the top

```
const bot = require("../bot.js")
```

and then later in execute function got the client. Aparantly this line was causing the bot to start when it tried to register slash commands